# How do I save a HttpPostedFileBase file to my Byte[] (array) variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I save a HttpPostedFileBase file to my Byte[] (array) variable?
I would like to be able to only get the data in Request.Files[upload].
I would like to be able to pass arond the Byte array which is a file to do validation on the server before doing:

`File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)` 
and saving teh file on the file server.

In my view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload",
                          "Upload", 
                          FormMethod.Post,
                          new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

  { <label for="file">Upload Image:</label> 
         <input type="file" name="FileUpload" /><br />
         <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />

 }
```

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //HttpPostedFileBase request = file; 
        foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
        {

          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*********************savepath:" + Request.Files[upload].FileName+"********************");

            string savePath = "C:\desktop";
            string newPathForFile = Path.Combine(savePath, Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName));
            Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(savePath, newPathForFile));
        }

        return View("Home");
    }
```

Comment: Edit your question and explain why it isn't a duplicate of that question, then it'll be reviewed.

Comment: Those are methods. Have you checked [HttpPostedFileBase properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Oh I see the "The File property that you mention is part of another user's model. Simply refer to the InputStream, not the File" That was not immediately clear to me.

Comment: The `File` property that you mention is part of another user's model. Simply refer to the `InputStream`, not the `File`.